# sed how to append a comment after <?xml [something ?>

Tags: xml, sed, append

I want to add a comment right at the start of an xml-file. As the first line of any xml-file always has to be like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` My comment must be right after that.

This is as far as I get:

```
sed '/<\?xml.*\?>/a \<!-- comment -->' test.xml
```

This almost works, but the comment is also added after lines like

```
 <package xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" unique-identifier="uuid_id">
```

So there seems to be a mistake in my command. Can you help me?

Comment: that would give you malformed xml.  is that ok?

Comment: no, wouldn't be ok. why is it malformed? Thank you for the hint!

Comment: sorry, i am wrong.  a comment is ok there.  http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-prolog-dtd  ignore me.  :o(

Comment: Never mind! Always better to check once more :)

Comment: Do you mean the first line of any of your XML files? Because an XML declaration is recommended but not required for a valid XML document.

Comment: @MichałPolitowski yes, I mean the first line. Thanks for the information, but now as I have a working command, I can leave the XML declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

```
sed '/<?xml .*?>/a \<!-- comment -->' test.xml
```

(no backslash before the question mark)

Comment: alternatively/as well, add a space after the xml (and remove the other backslash)

Answer (score 1):

Your basic assumption:

> As the first line of any xml-file always has to be like `<?xml
>   version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

is quite wrong. The XML declaration can differ from this example, or it can be omitted entirely. And it doesn't have to be followed by a newline.

Doing any manipulation of XML with a non-XML-aware tool like sed is a bad idea if only because it doesn't take character encoding into account.